# Django: Extending to Other Pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Something is weird when I try to extend parts of 1 file to other files. I haven't used Django before and I am trying to learn how to do so.

I believe I figured out what the problem is, but I'm not sure how to solve it. I believe my problem has to do with the url file.

**url.py file #1:**

D:\learning\Django\pages\pages_project\urls.py

Code in the file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include # new

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('pages.urls')), # new
]
```

**url.py file #2**

D:\learning\Django\pages\pages\urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'), # new
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),

    ]
```

I want the top part of this file, to be found in the top part of the other files:

**Base.html file:**
[image: base.html file]

**Home.html file:**

[image: home.html file]

**About.html file:**

[image: about.html file]

What I believe the problem is but I am not 100% sure:

I believe it has to do with one or both of the URL files, is there a way I can print the location that each of these are looking at?

Comment: Show us your settings. I believe django templates is not working because of templates settings went wrong

Comment: Any particular part of the settings.py file I should paste?

Comment: Ohh!!!!!!!!! Yeah see the answer below. You must get that... That's quite stupid of you and me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are displaying these pages as HTML files. You have to run Django server and go to the URLs to display the pages.

Comment: I am getting an error message here when I run the server: 
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # new <---what looks weird about this?

Comment: Ah, I see what I did wrong, I put it in the wrong spot in settings. This seems to have done the trick.